# Sort By Price Ascending Does Not Work on Magento 2.4.1 and 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.2

I am not sure what happened, but when you try to sort by price in the ascending direction, prices do not look correct. It works just fine in descending order though.

Here is an example:
https://www.thegemlab.com/shop/jewelry/earrings?product_list_order=price

You'll see on the bottom of the first page two items that are listed as "Call for Price." Both of these are $0. It's fine if $0 are at the very end of all prices, but it's clearly not as there are 2 pages worth.

Answer (score 0):

Its not Magento 2.4.1 or 2.4.2 issue . their is some jquery conflict in plugin.
In my Case I disabld LayeredNavigation plugin then it works fine .Please Check it .

Comment: This is not the case. I disabled all third party plugins, and it's still the same. Have you tested it with $0? I know mostly everyone has prices for all products, but not with my clients specifically.